# Why does the equation for the effective density of states change with the semiconductor?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

The effective density of state $N_C$ of Silicon is $12(2\pi m_n kT/h^2)^{3/2}$ whereas it is equal to  $2(2\pi m_n kT/h^2)^{3/2}$ for GaAs where $m_n$ is the electron effective mass.

**How to explain this difference?**

Answer (score 2):

Silicon has 6 equivalent band minima in k-space.  GaAs has only one.  k-space is the space where we count the number of electrons.  The k's are valid quantum numbers for electrons. The second part of the equation is the formula for density of states in *each* band minimum.  That's why the factor in front is a factor of 6 higher for silicon than for GaAs.

[image]

The effective density of states is basically the number of states available to electrons at the band minima within a few kT of the conduction band minimum.